# How to pull a remote branch into a new local branch

Tags: git

Is there a single git command, that allow to pull a remote branch creating a new local branch with a custom name on the fly?

That is, an equivalent to

```
git fetch --all
git checkout remote_name/branch_name
git switch -c new_branch_name
git branch -u remote_name/branch_name
```

Comment: Sounds like you want to create an alias.

Comment: Maybe. If there isn't something built in, which does the trick already. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can pull a branch and create a new branch in one command, by doing:
`git pull origin <remoteBranchToPullFrom>:<NameForYourNewLocalBranch>`.

If you use the same name for both, you will just pull changes into that branch. If you use a new name for the second argument it will create a new branch.

Comment: Yes, that's close to what I want - thx!

Comment: Does it set up the branch as tracking branch?

Comment: I think it should, you can check this by running "git branch -vv" see docs: https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Branching-Remote-Branches

Answer (score 2):

This should work:

```
git checkout remote_name/branch_name -b new_branch_name
```

More information can be found here:
https://git-scm.com/docs/git-checkout#Documentation/git-checkout.txt--bltnew-branchgt

Comment: _almost_. This does not fetch.

Answer (score 1):

With [`git checkout`](https://www.git-scm.com/docs/git-checkout#Documentation/git-checkout.txt-emgitcheckoutemltbranchgt), it's (almost) a single command:

```
git fetch --all
git checkout -b your_local_name --track origin/remote_name
```

If you want to fuse fetching and checking out into a single command, consider defining an alias:

```
git config --global alias.fco \
  '!f() { git fetch --all; git checkout -b "$1" --track "origin/$2"; } f'
```

Then simply:

```
git fco your_local_name remote_name
```